# UI Routing issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm facing an issue while using (Multiple views, UI-route) widget wise implementation.

First page has one link ie Test.when we click on that link, three widgets(green,red,blue) will appear. Each widget have one link (eg:ADD A). when we click on that link another view appear(eg: edit a).

My problem is that When we click on ADD A link, 'edit a' view appear and then click on ADD B link, then appear 'edit b' view and but the 'edit a' view is disappeared.In this scenario I want to display both 'edit a' and 'edit b' views.

[Code in plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OIhXkSEeaG7gyb7kDYnT?p=preview)

```
<a  ui-sref="home">Test</a>

<div ui-view></div>
<div ui-view="chart"></div> 
<div ui-view="data"></div>
```

JS Code:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["ui.router"])
myapp.config(function($stateProvider){

     $stateProvider.state("home", {
        views: {
            "": {
                templateUrl: "a.html"
            },
            "chart": {
                templateUrl: "b.html"
            },
            "data": {
                templateUrl: "c.html"
            }
        }    
    })

     .state('home.Adda', {
      views: {

            "aAdd": {
                templateUrl: "a.a.html"
            }
        }   
    })

    .state('home.Addb', {
      views: {

            "bAdd": {
                templateUrl: "b.b.html"
            }
        }   
    })

    .state('home.Addc', {
      views: {

            "cAdd": {
                templateUrl: "c.c.html"
            }
        }   
    })
})
```

Comment: You can't implement such thing using UI-router, as you wanted to show to views at a time..which are totally dependant on nested state..

Comment: Ok thanks pankajparkar ,but how can i overcome this situation .Have any other option or procedure to solve this issue?